# Showing that $\int_{0}^{1}{x(x-1)(x+2)\over (x+1)^3}\cdot{1\over \ln(x)}dx={\ln{\pi\over 2}-{7\zeta(3)\over 4\pi^2}}$

Tags: integration

Showing that

> $$\int_{0}^{1}{x(x-1)(x+2)\over (x+1)^3}\cdot{1\over \ln(x)}dx=\color{brown}{\ln{\pi\over 2}-{7\zeta(3)\over 4\pi^2}}$$

Applying substitution

$u=\ln(x)\rightarrow du={1\over x}dx$ and $x=e^u$

$x=1\rightarrow u=0$ and $x=0\rightarrow u=-\infty$

Then

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{0}{e^{2u}(e^u-1)(e^u+2)\over u(e^u+1)^3}du$$

$${e^{2u}(e^u-1)(e^u+2)\over u(e^u+1)^3}=e^u-2+{e^{2u}+5e^u+2\over (e^u+1)^3}$$
Substitute back in
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{0}{e^u-2\over u}+{e^{2u}+5e^u+2\over u(e^u+1)^3}du$$

$e^{2u}+5e^u+2=A(e^u+1)+Bu(e^u+1)^2+Cu(e^u+1)+Du$

$u=0\rightarrow A=1$

I think it is impossible to find the values of B,C and D.

This method is not working. Can anyone give me a hint on another method?

Comment: apply the same tricks as in your other questions, using Taylor series and integrating term by term. And [partial fraction decomposition yields](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Apart%5Bx+(x-1)(x%2B2)+%2F+(x%2B1)%5E3%5D) $$\frac{x(x-1)(x+2)}{(x+1)^3} =1 -\frac{2}{x+1}-\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}+\frac{2}{(x+1)^3}$$

Comment: A very nice integral, connecting 3 fundamental constants

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x}{(1+x)\log x}\,dx =\log\frac{\pi}{2}\tag{1}$$
is a straightforward consequence of Frullani's theorem and Wallis' product.

So it is enough to compute:

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x}{(1+x)^3\log x}\,dx &=& \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-2x}}{x(1+e^{-x})^3}\,dx\\&=&-7\cdot\zeta'(-2)\tag{2}\end{eqnarray*}$$
always by Frullani's theorem. The reflection formula for the $\zeta$ function finishes the job.

Comment: As expected :) +1 !

Comment: Jack $(1)$ is straightforward by simply writing $\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}=\sum_{n\ge 0}(-1)^ne^{-nx}$, exploiting uniform convergence, applying Frullani and Wallis' product for $\pi/2$.  $(2)$ is not as clear and you might consider elaborating a bit.  -Mark

Comment: Slowly I will get there, at the moment I am walking in the dark forest.

Comment: How did you apply the Frullani's theorem in $(2)$?

Comment: @MarcoCantarini: by expanding $\frac{1}{(1+e^{-x})^3}$ as $\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n (n+1)^2 e^{-nx}$ we get $\eta'(-2)$ with $\eta$ being the analytic continuation of $$\eta(s)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s}$$

Comment: Probably is for my idiocy but I get a non convergent series in this way. Maybe I made some silly mistake. Thank you.

Comment: @MarcoCantarini: if you're an idiot, I am a donkey. The series you get by simply plugging in everything is divergent, you're right, that is the reason for which you need repeated integration by parts (to remove divergence) followed by the analytic continuation of the $\eta$ function. But anyhow, assuming that $$\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n (n+1)^{-s} \log(n)$$ is convergent in some sense, it has to converge to $\eta'(s)$. In our case, $s=-2$.